# Dev Express Scheduler

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I want to develop a WPF application (appointment system) using DevExpress Scheduler control. I am new to WPF and DevExpress. I am using v10.2 of DevExpress. The Official documentation available online is for v14.1. There is no enough document on v10.2.

My task is to bind data from the database to the scheduler on page load and allow user to add new appointments which should be reflected in the DB. I am using VS2010 and SQLServer. Please provide me any links to refer to in order to accomplish my task.

**Update:**

I referred to [link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2895) to bind SchedulerControl to SQL Server database, but the steps are not complete. I would like to know how to create dataset(CarsDBDataSet as given in the example) which in turn can be bound to scheduler. I am really confused with all this. No proper documentation where we can refer to.

Comment: What is wrong with documentation for v14.1? What have you tried?

Comment: I am referring to this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument8653). When I try to Specify Mappings I am not able to find AppointmentStorage.Mappings property. I think this must have been added new or changed the property name in v14.1. How can I use it in v10.2?

Comment: Also when trying to Bind the scheduler storage to appointment data using this:  `this.CarSchedulingControl.Storage.AppointmentStorage.DataSource = dataSet.CarScheduling;` I am getting error: ` Error 1 `'DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduler.SchedulerStorage' does not contain a definition for 'AppointmentStorage' and no extension method 'AppointmentStorage' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.Xpf.Scheduler.SchedulerStorage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Try to use `this.CarSchedulingControl.Storage.Appointments.DataSource`. If you go to [this](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2493) example, than you can see that you can change version of example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nempoBu4. The link helped a lot.

Comment: how can I find other examples in there?

Comment: Go to [examples](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/List/1) and set filter to `WPF\DXScheduler for WPF`. For each example you can select the version, but for some examples you cannot choose your version.

Comment: @nempoBu4 Please check my update. I am now stuck at binding sql db to the scheduler. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have the DevExpress account? If you have then you can download off-line documentation.

Comment: Go to [Download Manager](https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/DownloadManager/), select your product, select your version and download documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but I created my account just now. I do not have any products registered for that account.

Comment: Then you must to use account that you are used in installation of DevExpress components. Or try to ask DevExpress itself about old documentation.

Comment: I have mailed them. But till then f anyone could point me in the right direction then it would be very helpful. I would like to know how yo generate dataset from SQL server table

Comment: To generate dataset go to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx) MSDN article.

Answer (score 0):

According to comments:
0. Use `this.CarSchedulingControl.Storage.Appointments.DataSource` to set the data source.
1. You can found [examples](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/List/1) here. Set filter to WPF\DXScheduler for WPF. For each example you can select the version, but for some examples you cannot choose your version.
2. You can ask from DevExpress about old off-line documentation.
3. To generate dataset go to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx) MSDN article.
4. Another way to generate dataset from SQL is to use `System.Data.SqlClient` objects:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.WorkstationID = "Server";
builder.DataSource = "DataBase";
builder.UserID = "User";
builder.Password = "Password";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("Select Field1, Field2, Field3 From Table", connection);
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    var dataTable = new DataTable("Table");

    adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
}
```

So you can use this dataSet as DataSource for your Scheduler.